# `sort -t` doesn't work properly with string input

Tags: bash, shell, sorting

I want to sort some space separated numbers in bash. The following doesn't work, however:

`sort -dt' ' <<< "3 5 1 4"`

Output is:

`3 5 1 4`

Expected output is:

```
1
3
4
5
```

As I understand it the `-t` option should use it's argument as a delimiter. Why isn't my code working? I know I can `tr` the spaces to newlines, but I'm working on a code golf thing and want to be able to do it without any other utility.

EDIT: everybody is answering by splitting the spaces to lines. **I do not want to do this.** I already know how to do this with other utilities. I am specifically asking how to do this with sort, and sort only. If -t doesn't delimit input, what *does* it do?

Comment: How about this: `s="3 5 1 4"; sort <<< "${s// /$'\n'}"`?

Comment: or `printf "%s\n" 3 5 1 4 | sort`

Comment: The problem is `sort` works on lines.

Comment: @Cyrus if sort works on lines then what does the -t option do?

Comment: With `-t` you can define a field separator. To sort your /etc/passwd ascending by uid: `sort -t : -n -k3,3 /etc/passwd`

Comment: Note that `sort` is not part of bash. If you want bash code that sorts without splitting, it would be possible, though slow and awkward. Also, since you haven't specified an operating system, please let us know what version of `sort` you're running.

Comment: Oh, and also, you can't do what you're asking to do with any version of `sort` that I've ever heard of. Field separators are not record separators.

Answer (score 2):

Use process substitution with `printf` to have each input number in a separate line, otherwise `sort` gets only one line to sort:

```
sort <(printf "%s\n" 3 5 1 4)

1
3
4
5
```

While doing so `-dt ''` is not needed.

Comment: You can even drop the `-dt' '`

Comment: I am asking specifically how to do this with only sort. I know there are ways to do it with other commands. I said this in my question.

Comment: sort command needs input on separate lines. -t only separates fields in one line for sorting on individual fields.

Comment: @Markasoftware: I suggest you to remove `bash` and `shell` tags from your question.

Comment: @anubhava that was the issue, I thought it delimited records but it isn't actually for field. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around, I have discovered what -t is for. It is for delimiting a file if you want to sort by a certain part of each line, for e.g, if you have

```
Hello,56
Cat,81
Book,14
Nope,62
```

And you want to sort by the number, you would to -t',' to delimit by the comma and then use -k to select which part to sort by. It is for field delimiting, not record delimiting like I thought.

Comment: That's why people have been offering you workarounds. Now what are you planning to do with this question? Mark your own answer of "you can't do that" as the correct one? Or look at one of the alternatives that might actually get you to where you want to go?

Comment: @ghoti I stated in my question that I already knew about workarounds. I was wondering if there was an way to do this with sort only.

Comment: My question stands - what are you planning to do with this question? As-is, I suspect it will provide little benefit to the SO community, as the question assumes functionality which does not exist. If someone finds your question a year from now, what would you hope they get out of it? Can you improve it so that it communicates something more clearly? If not, consider deleting it.

Comment: @ghoti it does not allow me to delete it, as it has answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since sort only separates fields on a single line, you have no choice but to pipe data into `sort -dt` such as this method using `IFS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

var="8 3 5 1 4 7 2 9 6"
old_IFS="$IFS"

function main() {

IFS=" "
printf "%s\n" $var | sort -d

}

main
```

This will give an obvious output of:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

If this is not the way you wish to use sort well you have already answered your own question by doing a bit of digging on the issue which, if you would have done so before, would have saved time for the others giving answers as well as yours.